# Best way to call an observable in a service from a dumb/presentational component

Tags: angular, events, rxjs

I'm using the smart/dumb components pattern in Angular which means dumb child components are not allowed to inject services. In a dumb child component I'm creating there is a button with a click event that should result in a call to an observable method in a service injected in the smart parent component. What is the best way to connect the call to the services observable method from the dumb components click event?

I could emit an event from the dumb component to the parent component and then in the called method in the parent create a subscription to the service method. But that means an explicit subcribe which means an explicit unsubscribe is needed. It would be better if I could use the async pipe. I would prefer to just bind the service method to the dumb component using @input and then invoke with:

```
(click)="observable$ | async"
```

But that isn't a valid syntax for the click event.

So what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can handle the unsubscription in parent or use async pipe in parent. Normally click are the trigger of a series of events. You can chain them up and use it in view with async pipe. For example

suppose it is a click to get userdata

```
// child comp
this.childClickEvent=new EventEmitter()

// child view 
<button (click)="childClickEvent.emit()"></button>

// parent comp
this.childClick=new Subject()
this.userdata=childClick.pipe(switchMap(_=>http.get(userUrl)))

// parent view
<child-comp (childClickEvent)="childClick.next()"></child-comp>
<section *ngIf="userdata | async">{{userdata.name}}</section>
```

Comment: Thanks, in your example how do you access "childClick" from the parent?

Comment: Thanks. Do you prefer that over a manual subscribe in the component class?

Comment: Async pipe can’t apply to all the use cases, when the streams are complex composition. Sometimes u still have to use unsubscribe. But I use async pipe whenever possible

Comment: What do you think about this idea:

// child view 
<button (click)="clicked=true"></button>
<ng-template *ngIf="clicked && serviceCall$ | async"></ng-template>

// child component
@Input() methodInService$: Observable<void>;

//parent view
[methodInService$]="methodInService$"

//parent comp
methodInService$ = this.service.method$

Comment: You then have to maintain click variable status. Not worth it

Comment: Ok good point. If this was available (click)="observable$ | async" it would  be the best though, do you agree?

Comment: I will agree if outbound event provide an option to pass in observable. Maybe not in ur format but auto emission is the point